# Parsing a CSV file with rows of varying lenghs

Tags: parsing, csv

I am calling a webservice that's returning a comma separated dataset with varying columns and multiple text-qualified rows (the first row denotes the column names) . I need to insert each row into a database while concatenating the rows that are varied.

The data is returned like so

```
"Email Address","First Name","Last Name", "State","Training","Suppression","Events","MEMBER_RATING","OPTIN_TIME","CLEAN_CAMPAIGN_ID"

"scott@example.com","Scott","Staph","NY","Campaigns and activism","Social Media","Fundraiser",1,"2012-03-08 17:17:42","Training"
```

There can be up to 60 columns between `State` and `Member_Rating`, and the data in those fields are to get concatenated and inserted into one database column. The first four fields and the last three fields in the list will always be the same. I'm unsure the best way to tackle this.

Comment: You might want to note which languages or tools you would like the answer to use.

Comment: I am using ColdFusion, but AI didn't want to limit my answer to just CF folks. I assumed the solution could be language-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this solution fits your needs. I hope so. It's a `perl` script that joins with `-` surrounded with spaces all fields but first four and last three. It uses a non standard module, `Text::CSV_XS` that must be installed using `CPAN` or similar tool.

Content of `infile`:

```
"Email Address","First Name","Last Name","State","Training","Suppression","Events","MEMBER_RATING","OPTIN_TIME","CLEAN_CAMPAIGN_ID"
"scott@example.com","Scott","Staph","NY","Campaigns and activism","Social Media","Fundraiser",1,"2012-03-08 17:17:42","Training"
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ 
        allow_whitespace => 1,
});

open my $fh, q[<], $ARGV[0] or die qq[Open: $!\n];

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
        my $concat = join q[ - ], (@$row)[4 .. @$row-4];
        splice @$row, 4, scalar @$row - (3 + 4), $concat;
        $csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );
        print qq[\n];
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
"Email Address","First Name","Last Name",State,"Training - Suppression - Events",MEMBER_RATING,OPTIN_TIME,CLEAN_CAMPAIGN_ID
scott@example.com,Scott,Staph,NY,"Campaigns and activism - Social Media - Fundraiser",1,"2012-03-08 17:17:42",Training
```